# Opening modules from the OCaml compiler without building a custom toplevel

Tags: ocaml

I would like to have a few lines of code at the start of my OCaml input file to have toplevel remember the last expression typed all the time, under the name of `it`.  I.e., I want to have:

```
# 3 + 4;;
val it : int = 7
# it;;
val it : int = 7
# let foo = 42;;
val foo : int = 42
# it + 130;;
val it : int = 137
#
```

But I *don't* want to build a custom toplevel or use `camlp5` or anything fancy like that.

What I currently do (in OCaml version 4.02.3, I don't know why I have that version; but I hope the exact version doesn't matter?) is the following:

```
#directory "+compiler-libs";;

#load "/opt/src/ocaml-4.02.3/utils/warnings.cmo";;
#load "/opt/src/ocaml-4.02.3/parsing/location.cmo";;

let convert_phrase x =
  match x with
  | Parsetree.Ptop_def
        [{Parsetree.pstr_desc = Parsetree.Pstr_eval (e, a)}] ->
      Parsetree.Ptop_def
        ([{Parsetree.pstr_desc =
             Parsetree.Pstr_value (Asttypes.Nonrecursive,
               [{Parsetree.pvb_pat =
                   {Parsetree.ppat_desc =
                      Parsetree.Ppat_var (Location.mknoloc "it");
                    Parsetree.ppat_loc = Location.none;
                    Parsetree.ppat_attributes = []};
                 Parsetree.pvb_expr = e;
                 Parsetree.pvb_attributes = a;
                 Parsetree.pvb_loc = Location.none}]);
           Parsetree.pstr_loc = Location.none}])
  | x -> x;;

Toploop.parse_toplevel_phrase :=
  let parse_toplevel_phrase = !Toploop.parse_toplevel_phrase in
  fun x -> convert_phrase (parse_toplevel_phrase x);;
```

And that kind of works.

My question: if I just do the `#directory "+compiler-libs";;` thing, I can access the `Toploop` and `Parsetree` modules, but I cannot access the `Location` module!  What is the reason for that?  I find having to load `.cmo` files from my source directories very unattractive.

So is there a way to do what I want without having to have a source tree available?

Or, in other words: why the difference between `Toploop` and `Location`, in this respect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, what you should load is not individual `.cmo` files but

```
#load "ocamlcommon.cma";;
```

which is in `+compiler-libs` directory.

The differences between `Parsetree`, `Toploop` and `Location` are subtle...

In OCaml, data types and their constructors become accessible only with adding its directory to the load path (by `#directory "<dir>"`).  No object code loading (by `#load`) is required for them.

`Parsetree` is so called "mli only module": it has only data type definitions and no values are defined.  Therefore everything in `Parsetree` is accessible only by putting it into the load path.

`Location` defines types and values. Its data types and constructors are accessible without loading the object file but values require the loading.  In this case, the object `location.cmo` is loaded when you load `ocamlcommon.cma` which archives it.

`Toploop` is a tricky one.  You can access the values of `Toploop` even without loading `toploop.cmo`, since `Toploop` is linked and already available in OCaml toplevel.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! This totally solved my problem.

Comment: My confusion was that as a Coq user I think of constructors and functions as the same kind of thing, and `Parsetree.Ptop_def` *was* allowed. That's why I missed the difference between `Toploop` and `Parsetree`. Thanks again for the answer, and for the further clarification.